Página não é visualizada
[Cypress] Problema com carregamento de conteúdo após login
Estou enfrentando um problema ao automatizar testes com Cypress em uma página que estou testando. O fluxo é o seguinte: Realizo o login normalmente, e a aplicação redireciona para a segunda página.
O status da requisição é 200, mas o conteúdo da página não é carregado; a tela fica em branco. Já tentei algumas soluções baseadas em pesquisas nos fóruns, como configurar cy.intercept para monitorar as requisições e adicionar waits, mas até agora não tive sucesso.

Comentários foram movidos para o chat. Antes de postar um comentário, revise os propósitos dos comentários. Comentários que não solicitam esclarecimentos ou sugerem melhorias geralmente pertencem a uma resposta, em [meta] ou em [chat].
